# How can I make a site like StackExchange with Joomla?

Tags: module, extensions, extension-request

I really like stack exchange, you ask questions, get answers, vote for them and many more. I'd like to have a similar platform for my company so that employees can discuss different subjects and tag their discussions. Is there any module/extension for Joomla to do something similar?

Comment: EasyDiscuss is probably a close fit. Kunena may also be an option? SimAnswers is another. Based on that information try searching https://extensions.joomla.org/

Comment: EasyDiscuss is great for this sort of thing, so I second that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theres a whole [Questions and Answers category in the JED](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/communication/question-a-answers) including:

- [JE Stack Exchange](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/communication/question-a-answers/je-stack-exchange) (free)
- [JE Stack Exchange Pro](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/je-stack-exchange-pro) (paid)
- [Minitek Discussions Pro](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/communication/question-a-answers/minitek-discussions-pro?com_jed_extension_limitstart=18) (paid)

which seem to have the basic functionality of Stack Exchange.